# TcpClient Memory Leak

Tags: c#, networking, memory-leaks, tcpclient, connection

I have created a server that works perfectly. However when I decided to test it against a DDoS attack I found a major memory leak. The code below, will fill up RAM (when DDoS'd) and eventually crash my computer. I have tried to implement counter-measures however the memory leak still exists. My current code for listening is:

```
TcpClient connection = server.AcceptTcpClient();
if (!IpByConnection.ContainsKey(connection.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0])) {

    IpByConnection.Add(connection.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0], connection);

    CipherNetwork network = new CipherNetwork(connection);
    network.ListenOnDifferentThread(true);
    network.DisconnectOnError(true);
    network.StartListening();

    TotalConnections += 1;

} else {
    connection.Close();
}
```

How would I fix this memory leak ?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the method is run on a separate thread.
EDIT 2: I have tried setting it to null, disposing it and both.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Edited the post - added the question.

Comment: BTW. while unrelated to your problem, your service will fail if someone with a IPV6 address connects as many `:` exist within it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I plan to add IPV6 support once I get the core functionality complete.

Comment: Just cast `EndPoint` to a `IPEndPoint` and use the `Address` property. It says to do exactly that in [the documentation of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint.aspx) `RemoteEndPoint` (See the first paragraph of "Remarks")

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the tip. I'll implement it as soon as I get this problem resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a direct solution however I managed to solve the problem by limiting each connection 5 per IP, using A Dictionary to store the connected users and remove them once they disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You never remove remove the connection from `IpByConnection` so as connections come in your list will just grow larger and larger, you need some way for the connections that fail or are closed get removed from that collection. This is not specific to a DDoS attack, your program would crash for the same reasons after weeks/months without being restarted for the same reason, it would just be slower to happen.

How you remove those objects depend on what you are doing with that connection to decide when you are "done" with it and remove it from the collection.

Comment: I have debugged the code. It adds the connections once and then the if statement stops it being added again. The hastable remains at a count of 1.

Comment: @Brodie Yes, the problem is not the same connection conninging over and over again. The problem is if 2 million ***different*** IP's connect (which is what would happen in a DDoS attack), the program will have 2 million objects in the `HastSet` and there is nothing you have shown that will cause those objects to be removed. And if they are in the hash set setting it to `null` and trying to garbage collect will do nothing as the objects are "rooted" by the collection so are ineligible to be removed during a garbage collection.

Comment: I see that as being another problem but right now they're all originating from 127.0.0.1 and I'd like to know what's causing this. I see your point, and I do have a solution for that once I understand why this is leaking from the same IP. And where it does not constantly add it to the HashTable.

Comment: Well 127.0.0.1 the loopback address on your own computer, you are connectng to your self? if you type `localhost` that points to `127.0.0.1` if you used something else, many network drivers are smart enough to never put a packet on the network and redirect it to localhost if it sees it is talking to itself. Lastly, why are you dealing with sockets this day and age? There are many good libraries (WCF) out there that will abstract all of this away and even handle load balanceing to help with DDoS attacks. Another note, you keep saying `HashTable` Don't use that, you should use `Dictionary`

Comment: The connection is being received I have verified that. And I prefer to build from scratch. HashTable's have worked fine for now and I will update my code to better methods once I find the root of this problem. The connection is successful however it does not dispose the object. I have even tried calling the garbage collector. The root of the problem as far as I can tell is the AcceptTcpClient() but I don't know any way around this.

Comment: `HashTable` became "unofficially deprecated" when .NET 2.0 came out in **2005**. it is only in the framework for backwards comparability. [WCF is a part of the .NET framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if that makes your "I prefer to build from scratch" feel any better.

Comment: I'll look into improving my code and then reply back when I have finished the transformation. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Ah sorry, this is not what I'm looking for. I am using TcpClients and Sockets to be able to make it cross-platform at a later stage.

Comment: One of the many modes of WCF (in-fact the default one 99% of all tutorials use) is [SOAP based messages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96616/arxml11.htm) which is cross platform.

Comment: Then post your own answer and accept it or delete your question. Please don't just leave a question with no answer (and not enough details for anyone to leave an answer)